# Multiple docker nginx containers or single nginx docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

Im searching for best practice for multiple nginx containers with tld support. Please consider the following docker-compose file:

```
frontend:
    build:
      context: nginx/
    hostname: frontend-docker
    ports:
      - "32777:80"

backend:
    build:
      context: nginx/
    hostname: backend-docker
    ports:
      - "33777:80"

proxy:
  image: nginx
  hostname: proxy-docker
  links:
    - frontend
    - backend
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

**Description** As you see I can access frontend and backend at localhost:32777 and localhost:33777 but when I got to prod I want to access frontend at site.com and backend at backend.site.com. In that case comes `proxy` container that holds `server_name backend.site.com;` and `server_name site.com` and creates revers proxy to `http://frontend` and `http://backend`

**My question** is should I get rid of proxy container and put `server_name` part directly in `frontend` and `backend` container and even build one container called `web` that holds `backend and frontend` there.

In general splitting the containers in that way is more suitable in terms of configuration, env variables, build different images and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adressing `frontend` and `backend` containers directly from the outside most likely won't work because you can't bind port 80 to the host more than once.

If `frontend` and `backend` are different applications you might want to build images of them with different `Dockerfile`s.

While we're at it, you might want to look into a <del>simple</del> loadbalancing solution like https://traefik.io/ as frontend for your containers.
But maybe that's overkill for your current use case and you want to stick with your above configuration.

Comment: yep I can't bind two on port 80 but I can bundle all of them in to one container. They have images, different databases - this is way simplified configuration only for access them outside the world. Should I bundle into one nginx or into 3. What are the performance penalties?

Comment: Generally the more stuff you run (processes) the more resources you need. I prefer to separate concerns, so if `frontend` and `backend` do different stuff in a different environment, bundling them into one could be confusing.

And how much load is on `frontend` vs. `backend` and how much RAM they need? If you have more visitors/hits for the frontend (as I could imagine) you might want to start two or more containers to handle the requests. If that means you always have to include the resources need for the backend that'd be a bad idea. w/o knowing any details, I'd go for more than 1 img.

Comment: in general I had the same very reasons as you. but in my office we argue with colleagues that's why I decide too ask here. So in general if you want to expose only virtual host server name should you do in separate proxy container or that will be part from backend and frontend containers.

Comment: I see docker containers as services with ports for in- and output. The end.

Handling the front facing web server, routing, TLS certificates, etc. is someone elses job. So, yes, no `server_name` in the application containers.

Comment: Mh.. totally agree with you. Have you in mind what are performance penalties from such setup.. do you have some resource that benchmarks request per sec? I want to cover all the points.

Comment: No, but if you include `server_name` in your application image, you'll limit yourself to one running container. No scaling, no load balancing. Sound like you're confusing docker and virtual machines. They are services, not hosts.

Comment: ok long story short - my cto doesn't approve above setup despite the fact that I put exactly the same reasons as you why I did in that way. Last of the blockers is the performance for him- he wants me to reduce number of containers  and build it as one 'because there are part of the same' and he want to reduce number of running containers because of the performance. I gather arguements against that but since he is not agree to me I decide to check opinions  of the other ppl here

Comment: we got 4 containers in total + plus this proxy container - why? to answers I need to go in the kitchen in order to uderstand me fully- something I don't want to do due obvious reasons. However I don't to do wrong design and try to convince him against every doubt that he has about the solution

Comment: thanks for your answers and time you out in that thread. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the discussion